# Why am I getting an Uncaught DOMException error in my SharePoint online environment?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I'm using SharePoint online for my intranet environment and it's been working well.  I have a root site which is my homepage and about 3 subsites that site under it.  There isn't much in the way of custom code except a small piece of jQuery that I wrote which calls a news feed API.  That api is still working fine just now, I noticed today however that no matter which page I go to on any of my sites there is an error in the console windows which is as follows:

```
init.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
    at q (https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.7611.1204/init.js:1:171398)
    at https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.7611.1204/init.js:1:172275
    at arguments.(anonymous function) (https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.7611.1204/init.js:1:99755)
```

I removed all my custom code (my little jQuery script) but the error still seems to persist and it's appearing on every page.  Has anyone encountered an issue like this before?  Everything I use is pretty much out of the box SharePoint online so I'm not quite how this error has suddenly appeared.

Comment: This is a Microsoft error, just ignore it.

Comment: Microsoft programming error, but an annoying one since clients (the human kind) blame us for those red lines in the console. Cause of the error is a (Microsoft SharePoint) script line that tries to alter CSS rules; but since Chrome 64 the Chrome Browser does not allow altering sheets coming from another domain: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/a4ebe08c91e29140e700c7bae9b94f27a786d1ca